# Aliasing a template template parameters

Tags: c++11, templates

Is it possible to use the `using` keyword for aliasing a template template parameter?

```
template <template<int> class T>
struct Foo {
    using type = T;
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`using` *(or `typedef`)* always provide an alias for a **type**, never for an **higher-kinded type** *(template template parameter)*. What you can do is templatize the alias itself on the `int`:

```
template <template<int> class T>
struct Foo {
    template <int X>
    using type = T<X>;
};
```